# Всегда авторизует, какой бы пароль я не вводил

Tags: php

День добрый. У меня появился вопрос по поводу сессий.
Делал я систему авторизации для админ панели
Но после столкнулся с проблемой.Когда я авторизуюсь я попадаю в админ-панель, но по идеи можно обойти и просто зайти на прямую в адресной строке и для этого я использовал сессии. И по идеи если я не авторизован, меня должно перекидывать в окно, где написано Go to login page. Но если я переходу на прямую то меня перекидывает сразу в админ панель, хоть я и не был залогинин. Прошу вашей помощи.
 Я новичек в этом деле)

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['auth']){
 exit ('Go to login page');
}
?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
 <title>ADMIN <?php echo $_SESSION['auth']?></title>
</head>
<body>
Admin
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id568078_users', 'melon');
mysqli_select_db ($db, 'id568078_users');
$select = @mysqli_query($db, "SELECT log,passw FROM test1 ");
if (!$select) exit ('#110');
$row = @mysqli_fetch_row ($select);
if(!row) exit ('#111');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Админ Панель</h1>
<div style="background-color: #d3d3d3; width: 200px; padding: 10px">
 <form method="post">
 login:<br>
 <input name="log" type="text"><br>
 password:<br>
 <input name="passw" type="password"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="button" style="cursor: pointer"><br><br>
 </form>
 <?php
 if($_POST['button']){
  $log = $_POST['log'];
  $passw = $_POST['passw'];

  if(($log == $row[0]) and ($passw == $row[1])){
    
   echo "Enter to admin -> <a href='admin.php'> admin </a>";
  }else{
   return exit ('Not correct');
  }
 }
 ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$select = @mysqli_query($db, "SELECT log,passw FROM test1 ");` - интересный запрос который всегда что то вернет если есть в таблице хоть одна запись. А почему у автора урока не спросите?

Comment: Вас ввели в заблуждение это урок как ненадо писать.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['auth']){
    exit ('Go to login page');
}else{
echo' 
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
    <title>ADMIN <?php echo $_SESSION['auth']?></title>
</head>
<body>
Admin
</body>
</html>';
}
?>
```

Вот это должно сработать.Но советую для начала ознакомится с $_COOKIE

Comment: К сажелению проблема глубже у вас и так выполниться exit а это значит что скрипт прекратит свою работу и естественно буфер вывода не будет сформирован. else не исправит проблему.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$urlToLogonPage = 'http://site.com/login';
if( ! $_SESSION['auth']){
    header('Location: ' . $urlToLogonPage );
    exit;
}
```

... остальной код